# Install init scripts manually under Debian Wheezy

Tags: init-script, sysvinit

I played around with LSB-compatible init-scripts under Debian Wheezy (`init` is from sysvinit package version 2.88dsf-41+deb7u1). My script in the `/etc/init.d` directory is as follows:

```
root@T60:~# ls -l /etc/init.d/test-script
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 811 Aug 10 03:18 /etc/init.d/test-script
root@T60:~# cat /etc/init.d/test-script
#! /bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          test
# Required-Start:    $all
# Required-Stop:     $all
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: test script
# Description:       test script
### END INIT INFO

# always executes
touch /var/test-file

case "$1" in
  start)
    echo "Starting script test"
    touch /var/test-file-start
    ;;
  stop)
    echo "Stopping script test"
    touch /var/test-file-stop
    ;;
  restart)
    echo "Restarting script test"
    touch /var/test-file-restart
    ;;
  force-reload)
    echo "Force-reloading script test"
    touch /var/test-file-force-reload
    ;;
  status)
    echo "Status of test"
    touch /var/test-file-status
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/test-script {start|stop}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
root@T60:~#
```

As a next step I added symlink to `/etc/rc3.d` directory:

```
root@T60:~# file /etc/rc3.d/S05test-script
/etc/rc3.d/S05test-script: symbolic link to `../init.d/test-script'
root@T60:~#
```

Now if I changed my runlevel from 2 to 3 I expected script to be executed, but this did not happen:

```
root@T60:~# who -r
         run-level 2  2014-08-01 20:47                   last=S
root@T60:~# init 3
root@T60:~# who -r
         run-level 3  2014-08-10 03:27                   last=2
root@T60:~# ls -l /var/test*
ls: cannot access /var/test*: No such file or directory
root@T60:~#
```

I am aware that I could use `insserv` or `update-rc.d` to install scripts and then they will work as expected. Am I correct that both `insserv` and `update-rc.d` take some additional steps when enabling the script besides installing the symlinks? If yes, then which steps?

Comment: Assuming you didn't create symlink `/etc/rc2.d/S??test-script`, your script should have run. To debug this, switch back to runlevel 2, add `set -x` as the second line of `/etc/init.d/rc`, and switch back to runlevel 3. Post the complete trace.

Answer (score 1):

You can automatically create the `/etc/rcX` symlinks using the `update-rc.d` command. [Here is some more information about update-rc.d](http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-managing-services-with-update-rc-d/).

In your particular example, this should do it:

```
update-rc.d test-script defaults
```

To remove it later, use:

```
update-rc.d -f test-script remove
```

Answer (score 0):

did you make the link in rc2.d (same link as in rc3.d) as well ?

Basically, when going from run level X to run level Y,

- all file in rcX.d starting with K (kill) will be run in alphabetical order with stop as unique arguement
- all file in rcY.d starting witk S (start) will be run in alphabeical order with start as unique argument

Comment: I did not make a symlink to `/etc/rc2.d`.

Comment: @Martin If you'd made a symlink `/etc/rc2.d/S??test-script`, then the `start` action would have been skipped on a 2→3 transition, on the assumption that the service was already running. If you haven't then your service should have run.