# Init script to run a script as specific user

Tags: shell-script, rhel, init-script

```
/apps/data/service/bin/startup.sh
```

This is the script i want to be executed during RHEL booting. I want it to be run in runlevel 3 only.

And i want this script to be started as specific user, eg:**appadmin**

So, what's the recommended way of achieving this? I read lot of posts on this, and I am confused now.

Just creating a soft link for */apps/data/service/bin/startup.sh* under */etc/init.d* would be enough to start the script? Is my understanding right?

Since i want the script to be ran as specific user, should i create a file under init.d like below?

```
su appadmin -c "/apps/data/service/bin/startup.sh"
```

and make it executable?

Comment: You almost did it.  see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149462/install-init-scripts-manually-under-debian-wheezy/

Comment: Keep in mind, rhel7 uses systemd. They have kept some initv script functionality, but you're admonished in that case to use the "functions" interface. See Fraud's answer.

Comment: [Same question on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20229/how-to-run-an-application-at-startup-as-a-certain-user).

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely look into `/etc/init.d/functions`. There is a nice function called `daemon`. It will run your program as specified user.

Example:

```
daemon --user=your_user /apps/data/service/bin/startup.sh &>/dev/null & ← or some logfile maybe…
```

Init script you can copy from some other service ;-)

HTH, Cheers